# Using Android SDK classes in unit tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I started creating unit tests for my Android project.
I **understand** the difference between unit tests and instrumentation tests.

In my code I use android SDK's [android.location.Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class.
This class is used to represent a Geo location and as such is used extensively even in very fundamental classes of my application.

That causes an issue when trying to unit test on the JVM.
for instance a method which uses the getBearing() method, fails to run on the JVM and throws this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Method setLatitude in
>   android.location.Location not mocked.

Is there a way to add that class only to the unit test which will enable it to run on the JVM?
Is there another\smarter solution?

Comment: could you not create a mockLocation class which derives from Location, and override any methods that your test calls?

Comment: Found what I believe is the answer with Roboelectric's shadow classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe to have the answer with Roboelectric's shadow classes!